# How to programmatically add a user to a role?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, users

I want to programmatically add the current user to a role and also remove the  current user from a role in a php page i created . am really stuck. thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can do that like this :

```
$my_user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$my_user->set_role( "editor" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fleshing out the previous answer using an example with my code.

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
    echo "<pre>";
    $umeta=$prefix.'usermeta';
    $u=$prefix.'users';

    $sql ="select ID, display_name from $u where ID=1";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
    print_r($result);
    foreach($result as $value){
    print_r($value);
    $user_id = $value['ID'];
    $my_user = new WP_User($user_id );
    $my_user->remove_role( "Ladder" );
    print_r($my_user);
    }
    ?>
```